# spring.net nhibernate session/transaction per request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, spring.net

Does Spring.NET have any support (integration) with NHibernate that would eneble per request ISession and transactions?

I foung [this blog](http://hackingon.net/post/NHibernate-Session-Per-Request-with-ASPNET-MVC.aspx#comment), but it is a bit old one so I want to know if things have moved forward a bit and may be this is already integrated in Spring framework and I can only set it up with some configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it has, it's called "open session in view". Transaction support is available too, but it's not automatically "one transaction per request".

I think a good place for you to start would be [the NHibernate quickstart](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/nh-quickstart.html) in the Spring documentation. Both concepts are explained there.

Only just noticed the asp.net MVC tag; I think it should work, but I'm not quite sure. If you're using asp.net MVC 3, you should use [Spring 1.3.2](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPRNET/fixforversion/11814), which is due to release soon.

Comment: All right I see that I can put transactional attribute above my service layer methods that is basicly what I wanted for my trnsactions. Yes Im using MVC3. Im going to go ahead and try it.

Comment: It's best to put the transaction attributes on the services as you propose. There were some questions on that subject on SO some time ago.

Comment: When I use Spring 1.3.2 I cant use spring code config which is depentent on Spring 1.3.1 :(. Is it a must to use 1.3.2?

Comment: MVC 3 isn't officially supported by 1.3.1, but I haven't tried. I think the code config project has an MVC sample but it uses MVC 2.

Comment: Yes you are right, but anyway i treied and it did work(it did start up). But now open session in view doesnt seem to work with spring 1.3.1 code config 1.0.1 and asp mvc3. I get exception no session bount to thread :(. I guess Ill try to downdrade to asp mvc 2 - that sucks.

Comment: You can also check out the trunk of 1.3.2 en build your pre-release version of Spring 1.3.2. We did that to get NHibernate 3.0 support to work with Fluent NHibernate - worked OK.

Comment: actualy I did already made fluent nhibenate to work with 1.3.1 (iveriden LocalSessionFactoryObject) and now again in problems with asp mvc3 :(

Comment: There's nothing that should hinder you from using MVC3, NH with 1.3.1 and OSIV, we are using it for a project started in April.