# Spring do not close session after nhibernate transaction

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, spring.net

I have the following declaration code:

```xml
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="TransactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="Get"/>
        <tx:method name="Update"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

I call methods "Get" and "Update" from function "X".

Method "Update" throw exception "Different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session"

How to close session during Spring after execute method?

**Update info:**

I will try to describe problem more precisely.

I have mvc project. Conrolers call managers (they represent business logic). Managers use Repositories for interacting with db.
At the update action I do the following things:

- call Get method of the manager for getting Account
- change some properites
- call Update method of the manager for updeting this account.

Each function of the manager is wraped into transaction by AOP.
When I call Update method it writes error. Looks that it is because Account object still attached to the session which was opened for Get function.
I tried to open and close session directly at the Get function (without AOP). All works correct in that case.

So the question is why Account object still attached to the session after Get call?

> Imho you are not using Interfaces for your Repo and spring fails to build the AOP decorator.

I am using interfaces for manager. I tested rollback of the transaction. It works, so i think that AOP decorator is build.

Comment: Do you call the methods from within the same object? How is your nh session scope configured?

Comment: <object id="NHibernateSessionFactory" type="Woffer.NhibernateRepository.FluentSessionFactory, Woffer.NhibernateRepository">
        <property name="DbProvider" ref="DbProvider" />
    </object>

    <object id="TransactionManager" type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.HibernateTransactionManager, Spring.Data.NHibernate31">
        <property name="DbProvider" ref="DbProvider"/>
        <property name="SessionFactory" ref="NHibernateSessionFactory"/>
    </object>

Comment: Can you please post the code where you call `Get` and `Update` and the implementation of `Get` and `Update`. Imho you are not using Interfaces for your Repo and spring fails to build the AOP decorator.

Comment: I will try to describe problem more precisely.

I have mvc project. Conrolers call managers (they represent business logic). Managers use Repositories(DAO) for interacting with db.
At the update action i make next things:
- call Get method of the manager for getting Account
- change some properites
- call Update method of the manager for updeting this account.

Comment: Each function of the manger are wraped into transaction by AOP.
When I call Update method it writes error described above Looks that it is because Account object still attached to the session which was opened for Get function.
I tried to open and close session directly at the Get function (without AOP). All works correct in that case.

So the question is why Account object still attached to the session after Get call?

Comment: > Imho you are not using Interfaces for your Repo and spring fails to build the AOP decorator.
I am using interfaces for manager. I tested rollback of the transaction. It works, so i think that AOP decorator is build.

Comment: @Christo: these comments provide useful information! Consider moving them into your question.

Comment: @Christo: +1, now it's a clear question

Answer (score 2):

From the comments to your question, I understand that your AOP proxies are correctly configured. I understand you have a manager class like this:

```cs
public class Manager : ISomeInterfaceToProxy
{
  object Get(...) {}
  void Update(object toUpdate) {}
}
```

This manager class is adviced with the transaction interceptor from your question.
This manager is injected onto your controller, which first calls `Get()` (initiating and completing the first transaction) and then `Update(...)`. It is important to realize that the call on `Update(...)` initiates *a second transaction*, which might result in the error you mention when the session scope is not "per request". If it does not find a session, each transaction will create new session.

There are several solutions:

1. Make sure your session stays open during the entire web request, e.g. use open session in view as in [spring.net nhibernate session/transaction per request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691506/spring-net-nhibernate-session-transaction-per-request)
2. Call the `Get(...)` and `Update(...)` routines from within another method that is wrapped in a transaction advice, such that the transaction is propagated between method calls